# A problem with penetration of ultrasound wave

Tags: acoustics

I am working on a model using ultrasound waves in medical field.
The idea is to put some layers and use ultrasonic module to determine a certain layer depth.

The problem is, I am using an $40 \text {kHz}$ ultrasound wave and I can't find any material that this wave can penetrate without much loss.

Comment: How much percentage loss is occurring?

Comment: So what is the question (I don't see a question mark there) ?

Comment: the question is is there any material that a can use in the model so the wave can penetrate it without much loss ??

Comment: i don't know the exact percentage of the loss unfortunately

Comment: But wouldn’t you get the layer depth from the loss information as long as there is enough signal to be detected on the other side?

Comment: actually i am using only one sensor for this so what i get is the distance of the obstacle .

Comment: If you detect the wave without any obstacle, you’ll get some intensity. Now if you place an obstacle in the middle you’ll get a different intensity. If you place an obstacle twice as thick in the same place, you’ll get some other intensity. Wouldn’t you get the thickness info from the difference?

Comment: ok i will work on this idea thanks very much

Comment: In the medical field ultrasound machines typically use 4-40 MHz signals,  roughly 1000 times greater than yours,  to get 0.1-1mm resolution.  40 KHz will only be capable of approximately 1 M resolution. [ that is talking about the center frequency of a pulsed 3-4 cycle signal ]